# Disable any popup , When clicked on particular link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I am using popup advertising in my website.So it basically opens ads when clicked inside body.

But I want to disable any popups when link with class `donot` is clicked.
Right now when below  link is clicked , popup opens and the `donot` link wont work.

```
<a class="donot" href="http://google.com">link</a>
```

I want To disable all popup activities and open the link when class donot is clicked
I tried below

```
$(".donot").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

});​
```

I am unable to find anything in popupcode .Here is my adnetwork popup code http://jsfiddle.net/hsz2hyvw/

Here is demo of popup opening http://jsfiddle.net/hsz2hyvw/3/

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hsz2hyvw/4/. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Sushil : I want to the link to be opened and want to disable the popup.

Comment: oh. ok. my bad i got ur question wrong. can you share ur popup code? ur fiddle doesn't work.

Comment: here is the poopup code http://jsfiddle.net/hsz2hyvw/3/

Comment: what is this popup code supposed to do? it doesn't open a popup. can you share the name of the popup plugin or the site where you're using this from?

Comment: @Sushil : Please check this.. click anywhere in body it opens popup http://jsfiddle.net/s3jvnLqn/ ,, I want to disable popup when clicked on link

Comment: i still cant get your popup to show up on clicking the body @DevakiDarshini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('donot')) {
        return false;
    }
    alert('d');
});​
```

**[Working Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hsz2hyvw/1/)**

Comment: Not working . Please check this..Its opening popup http://jsfiddle.net/hsz2hyvw/3/